GitHub - difference between `/contents/` and `/blobs/` API endpoints
I have a list of JSON files in GH to be fetched via API.
For this, I first use the /git.trees API endpoint to get a list that contains path and url info.
Next, there seem to be 2 options for getting the file contents:

use the path value from the above response in the 'get repository content' API

use the url value from the above  response in the 'get a blob' API


Are there any conditions for which one to select in which scenario?

The contents API is a newer API intended to be used with UI applications that display files differently based on their type, e.g. symlinks vs regular files. It uses file’s path as a key for retrieval.
Blobs API is older and simpler API that is used for simple file contents retrieval - no metadata. It uses files’s SHA as a key for retrieval.
When starting with the trees API, using blobs API for content is easier because trees API provides blobs url to retrieve the the files’s content.

yup, i figured out that i had to create the path from tree data for using the content API, but for blobs i can just use the url. the UI perspective i was not aware of. thanks!
